# Simple - Plotting a function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Why does this not plot?

```
Clear[x, b]
b = 2
f[x_] := b^x 

Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 5}]
```

The Plot simply generates and empty graph.

Comment: [Better place](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) to get better and probably quicker answers.

Comment: @Lion.  Provided that the Duplicate Police and Serial Closers don't get you...

Answer (score 3):

This plots just fine for me in Mathematica 8.

Something to note though, you don't really want to do := in the function declaration here. 
:= Postpones mathematica evaluating the function until it is actually called, and then it evaluates with the arguments given.

Basically, the rule I use is if I don't have a reason to use :=, I don't use it.

Good luck.

**Edit**
I just noticed you didn't clear f, that could be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ClearAll[f, b];
b = 2;
f[x_] := b^x

Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 5}]
```

[image]